# Is Cantor’s diagonal logic right?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I read an interesting discussion about diagonalization and diagonal methods in the debate following the question: Is the author Hofstadter cheating in his argument on completeness applying Cantor's Diagonal Proof to Gödel's (natural number) Numbering?
I note from the Wikipedia article about Cantor’s diagonal argument:

…Therefore this new sequence s0 is distinct from all the sequences in the list. This follows from the fact that if it were identical to, say, the 10th sequence in the list, then we would have s0,10 = s10,10. In general, we would have s0,n = sn,n, which, due to the construction of s0, is impossible. In short, by its definition s0 is not contained in the countable sequence S….(I apologize for the indexing which doesn't come out right)

Here Cantor presents a way of reasoning saying that if a number's components are different from other numbers’  components in a decimal expansion (or similar in base 2 or any other base) they must be different. This is obviously not necessarily the case for the popular numbers on this site 0.100000… and 0.099999… (I took instead two numbers in the $0<x<1$ Interval), assuming we attribute the same values to these two numbers.

I realize that 1.0000…and 0.99999… are popular items here and that this may have come up. I have searched some of the posts for “Cantor” and so far found none (not to say that it doesn’t occur, there are some 20 or so questions about this).

My question is now can we be sure that Cantor's implied rules for numbers represented as infinite series of numbers are similar to those we are used to?

.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Cantor's implied rules for numbers represented as infinite series of numbers"?

Comment: In base $b>2$ there will be no problem. For example in base $10$ you can form the new sequence from the diagonal by replacing 7s with 3s and the rest with 7s => the problem you describe does not occur. In base two there is a problem, but as the set of real numbers is independent from a choice of base, there is no problem with Cantor's conclusion.

Comment: To hot-queen: If the decimal representation of two numbers are different they must be different just as you might say that 0.3 is cannot be equal to 0.4.

Comment: All pairs of decimal expansions describing the same number are of the form you describe (i.e. one ends with an infinite string of $9$s, the other with $0$s). It isn't hard to avoid these when describing the "diagonal" decimal different from each number on the list - you only require that its $n$-th digit is different from the $n$-th digit of the $n$-th number in the list, so you have $9$ different choices. You can just avoid $0$ and $9$ as well, and you still have $7$ (at least) choices for each digit.

Comment: @Mikal, that is not correct, as you pointed out yourself. Any rational number with a terminating decimal expansion can also be terminated with a sequence of 9s. Decimal representation is not unique.

Comment: Lahtonen is describing the mechanics of contructing two infinite and different numbers. I am addressing the next step where Cantor says because they are different in all their decimal (or base 2 ) components the number they represent must therefore be different.

Comment: I don't think Cantor's argument "implied" that.

Comment: @Tressler, If they are not unique could we then not speculate that Cantor's number - not in the list - also might be equal to one of those on the list , these numbers not being unique? This is the essence of my point by the way.

Comment: @MikaelJensen What I think you are really asking is "given two different infinite decimal expansions, when do they represent two different real numbers?" This is a good question, particularly as you have already pointed out that the answer is "not always". I tried to explain in my comment why they represent two different numbers often enough that Cantor's argument still works. If you construct your expansion not on the list in the way that Jyrki suggests then you can in fact guarantee that it is a different number from any on the list.

Comment: @pressland and Lahtonen I had the feeling that Lahtonen had some rules in mind to avoid those particular problems. I imagine Cantor went through that process but I haven't seen it systemetically explained. You need to see that there is a possibility for a systematic avoidance of (in base two) 0.1111..and 0.01111. and 0.001111 etc, i.e. room for ending up with a unique number. I don't see that as trivial but I note you get punished by minus every time you mention infinite problems related to the real numbers (which will never stop me).

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is, yes, Cantor's logic is right. It has survived the best efforts of nuts and kooks and trolls for 130 years now. It is time to stop questioning it, and to start trying to understand it.

Comment: @MikaelJensen You are right that Cantor's argument must be arranged in such a way as to avoid the phenomenon of two decimal representation of the same number. The key to avoiding it is to observe that this phenomenon happens only when one of the two representations ends with infinitely many 0's and the other ends with infinitely many 9's. So you can avoid the problem by never using 0 or 9 as a digit when you construct the "diagonal" number. Jykri's suggestion to use only 3's and 7's does the job.

Comment: @MikaelJensen In one of your comments, you seem particularly interested in the case of base 2, where the "use 3 and 7" technique isn't available. What I would do, if I had to carry out Cantor's argument in base 2, is to make my diagonal number $d$ differ from the $n$-th number in the given sequence in position $2n$ rather than position $n$. I can still choose the odd-position digits of $d$ arbitrarily; I choose them to be alternately 0 and 1. Then there is no other binary representation of my $d$, so there is no problem with the argument.

Answer (score 6):

Cantor's proof works with binary sequences as basic objects and is independent of any interpretation of such sequences as real numbers. His proof can be formulated even without reference to sequences, in the following disguise: There is no surjective map of any set $A$ onto its power set ${\cal P}(A)$. Here it goes:

Let $A$ be any set, and let $$\phi:\quad A\to{\cal P}(A),\quad x\mapsto S_x\subset A$$
be a map that produces for each point $x\in A$ a subset $S_x$ of $A$. Consider now the special set
$$S^*:=\{x\in A\>| x\notin S_x\}\ \subset A\ .$$
As in Cantor's "diagonal proof" one shows that there cannot be an $x^*\in A$ with $\phi(x^*)=S^*$.

It's another story that binary (or decimal) sequences can be put into a more or less $1:1$ correspondence with the real numbers in the interval $[0,1]$, so that in the end Cantor's proof shows that the real numbers form an uncountable set. In detail, the situation is as follows:

We consider decimal sequences $a:=(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ with $a_n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$. By Cantor's proof the set $X$ of such sequences is uncountable. To each such sequence corresponds an unique number
$$\nu(a):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\>10^{-k}$$
in the interval $[0,1]$. It is a fact (not to be proven here) (a) that any real number $\alpha\in[0,1]$ has a decimal representation, which means that there is a sequence $a$ of the above kind with $\nu(a)=\alpha$, and (b) that any $\alpha\in[0,1]$ has at most two decimal representations, or preimages in $X$. Therefore, if $[0,1]$ were countable, we could count it using odd numbers only and then get a bijection of $X$ to some subset of ${\mathbb N}$ using the even numbers in cases were an $\alpha\in[0,1]$ has two decimal representations.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with your terminology being an amateur. I would like to see if my objection addressed, namely that the last step in Cantor’s proof i.e. that 2 different infinitely represented numbers are not necessarily different in their values, since I have shown that in one particular case two such numbers can have the same value, 1.000… and 0.nnnnn… where n is the chosen base minus 1 (actually an infinitely number of cases such as 0.9999… and 0.09999 equals 1 and 0.1 respectively).  There may of course be a way around this which i believe Lahtonen is indicating above.

Comment: @Mikael: The problem is that you are attributing a certain argument to Cantor that he never made.  Cantor did not prove the uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$ via a diagonalization argument: he proved the uncountability of the set of infinite binary sequences (which is just the uncountability of the power set of the natural numbers in a light disguise).  His proofs of uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$ were different.  All this can be found in the wikipedia article "Cantor's diagonal argument", for instance.

Comment: Later authors observed that the diagonalization argument can be used to prove the uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$: here it is easiest to use decimal expansions, and one must address the fact that every rational number has two different decimal expansions, one ending in $99999\ldots$ and the other in $0000\ldots$.  This fact *is* addressed in any number of places, e.g. as follows: when you change the $n$th digit of the $n$th term of the sequence, you have $9$ possibilities to change it to, hence at least $7$ possibilities other than $0$ or $1$.  So just agree never to change it to $0$ or $1$!